# How does type inference work with overloaded generic methods

Tags: c#, generics, type-inference

I have these classes:

```
/* Data classes */

public class Data
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class InfoData<TInfo> : Data
    where TInfo: InfoBase
{
    public TInfo Info { get; set; }
}

/* Info classes */

public abstract class InfoBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public interface IRelated
{
    IList<InfoBase> Related {get; set;}
}

public class ExtraInfo : InfoBase, IRelated
{
    public string Extras { get; set; }

    public IList<InfoBase> Related { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have two generic methods with this signature:

```
public TData Add<TData>(TData data)
    where TData: Data

public TData Add<TData, TInfo>(TData data)
    where TData: InfoData<TInfo>
    where TInfo: InfoBase, IRelated
```

Now when I create an instance of `Data` class and call `Add` method

```
// data is of type Data
Add(data);
```

The first generic method is used and generic type `Data` is correctly inferred.

But when I call the same method with a more implemented type object instance

```
// data is of type InfoData<ExtraInfo>
// ExtraInfo is of type InfoBase and implements IRelated
Add(data);
```

I would **expect the second generic method to be invoked**, but to my surprise it's not. If I check generic type constraints on the second one being:

```
where TData: InfoData<TInfo>
where TInfo: InfoBase, IRelated
```

The first one matches and the second one as well. And these types are more implemented than simple `Data` type if that makes any difference.

### Working example

[Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aq325B) is a working .Net Fiddle for you to play with.

### Questions

1. <strike>Why is second method not being called because both generic type constraints match and could be inferred?</strike>
2. How can I rewrite my second `Add` method so type inference would work and won't have to explicitly provide these types just to make sure that correct overload is being used?

### Edit

I've found the answer to my first question in [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx)

> The compiler can infer the type parameters based on the method arguments you pass in; it cannot infer the type parameters only from a constraint or return value.

In my case the first generic type can be inferred directly from parameter, but second one is more tricky. It can't be inferred from parameter only. Type constraint should be used, but compiler doesn't evaluate it.

I also have one possible solution to my second question that changes one type to concrete and keeps the other one generic.

```
public InfoData<TInfo> Add<TInfo>(InfoData<TInfo> data)
    where TInfo: InfoBase, IRelated
```

But I'm wondering if there's a more general/generic way of mitigating around this problem so I can still keep both type parameters but somehow have both types as generic?

Comment: Because InfoData inherits from Data. So instance of InfoData is Data => fire first method.

Comment: @Zilog: As you're explaining it if I change method order the other one would get called? I don't think compiler evaluates method suitability as you explained it. There's likely a more complex process involved that I would like to know about so I can mitigate it.

Comment: I don't think the sequence will mater. I just think (I am not sure) the where constrain on first method is too weak. InfoData is Data so both types triggers first method.

Comment: I also don't understand how compiler should evaluate TInfo in your second Add method. It has only one parameter.

Comment: I thought compiler uses some sort of *specificity* and decides to call the most specific method. In this case the second one. Evaluation of `TInfo` is through first generic type constraint. but if compiler doesn't do that maybe it could be mitigated in a different way so it can be inferred directly from parameters...? Maybe? Suggest a solution.

Comment: @Zilog: While writing my previous comment you pointed me in the right direction. I actually checked whether type inference uses type constraints at all. A quick search for "*generic method type inference based on constraints*" got me the answer I was looking for my first question. Have you got a solution for my second question?

Comment: What does the overload buy you, really? In particular, is it OK to call `Add` on an `InfoData` instance that happens to be stored in a field of type `Data` (which will always pick `Add<TData>()`? If it's not, the overload won't prevent that from happening. If it is, you don't really need the overload.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: What does it buy me? Unified calls upwards. All calls would be just simple method invocations without any additional checks beforehand to determine which method overload should be used ... That's what it would give me. **Simplified code** to all callers.

Comment: But if `.Add<TData>()` always works, what's simpler for callers then to always call that?

Comment: @JeroenMostert: **Exactly!** What simpler for callers than calling `Add(data)`. You've just answered your own question. It's the implementation that I'm mostly interested in to not end up with one multi-faceted complex and hard to maintain method but rather to have several simple methods and compiler works out which one is applicable for each individual invocation. *Let me write this code first so later it can be as easy as possible to use* - scenario...

Comment: Then, I'm sorry to say, what you want isn't possible. The compiler can't figure out that `.Add((Data) new ExtraInfo())` (contrived, but you get the issue) is supposed to call your "more specialized" method, rather than the one matching the argument type. If you are concerned about a simple *implementation*, either call the second method `AddInfoData` so callers are forced to pick the "right" one, or use double dispatch to benefit from virtual methods (`Foo.Add(Data)` invokes `Data.AddTo(Foo)` which `InfoData` overrides), where the correct method will be called at runtime.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: Well my solution in *Edit* provides exactly what I'm after but I'm wondering if it's still possible to stay with base classes and not write overloads with more inherited types.

Comment: Probably you can copy `data` reference as `dynamic data0 = data` and call the method like `Add(data0)`. This way it should find the most specific method runtime (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx).

Comment: (I just tryed it out on the fiddler site and my dynamic idea did not work out.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your Add methods are in the class named DataCollector;
you can add extension method which accepts `InfoData<ExtraInfo>` and returns the same type as shown below.

```
public static class DataCollectorExtensions
    {
        public static InfoData<ExtraInfo> AddInfoData(this DataCollector dataCollector, InfoData<ExtraInfo> data)
        {
            return dataCollector.Add<InfoData<ExtraInfo>, ExtraInfo>(data);
        }
    }
```

In this way you have to specify the generic parameters only once inside the extension method and use the extension method elsewhere without need to specify generic parameter.

```
new DataCollector().AddInfoData(new InfoData<ExtraInfo>());
```

You still have to name the method other than Add (I have named AddInfoData) otherwise compiler again picks up the `public TData Add<TData>(TData data)` method in the the DataCollector class.
As you're infact adding InfoData this method name should be acceptable.
I suppose this solution should be acceptable for all practical purposes.

Comment: I'm using a similar alternative although I've written extension methods directly on the classes themselves (as that's more suitable  in my case) and used those... While still using type inference which you (*almost*) elegantly avoided.

Comment: [This is what I'm using](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jQFC5Y) in the end. All generic types are inferred, but I do have to use pairs of `TData` and `InfoData<TInfo>` methods respectively.